# Proving that Non-Defective Matrices with Repeated Eigenvalues Have Complete Eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form, generalized-eigenvector

Is it always the case that for **non-defective matrices** the *geometric multiplicities* (dimensions of the eigenspaces) of the eigenvalues will equal the *algebraic multiplicities* ? What theorems are used in proving this statement ?

Take the $n \times n$  matrix $A$ with $\lambda_{1} \dots \lambda_{k}$ distinct eigenvalues but $k < n$. For each eigenvalue, if the dimension of the eigenspace $\varepsilon_{A}(\lambda_{k})$ is $d_{k}$ and $\sum\limits_{k} d_{k} = n$, then the matrix is non-defective and it is possible to build a set of linearly independent eigenvectors that spans $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (i.e a basis) to diagonalize A.

Collecting this basis in the matrix $P$, we can diagonalize the matrix via the similarity transformation $D = P^{-1}AP$.